# Как правильно сохранять данные в игре unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

У меня есть класс в котором сделана сериализация и десириализация через json.
Как мне сохранить все нужные данные в один файл? Нужно создать класс где они все будут хранится? Но как их инициализировать, а после передавать в нужные классы при загрузке? Не совсем понимаю. Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Создать класс, заполнить его, сериализировать, сохранить как **один** файл, далее в обратную сторону. Если вы делаете кучу мелких, не связанных классов, чтож, вы ССЗБ (погуглите).

Answer (score 0):

Если ты сериализуешь класс с помощью `JsonUtility`, то это варка каши из топора, потому что сериализовать нужно только данные, иначе непонятно как построить архитектуру загруски. Познакомся с паттерном [Memento](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE).

---

Что касается в один файл... думаю из самого вопроса ясно, что должен быть обработчик данных, который при добавлении сущности, проверяет если что для него загрузить по его ключу, а по команде сохранения создает список [ключ, json].

```
[Serializable]
public struct MementoData 
{
   public string key;
   public string json;
}

// Можно сериализовать/десиарилизовать с помощью JsonUtility все данные
[Serializable]
public struct MementoDataCollection 
{
   public MementoData[] data;
}
```

Все сущности само собой под интерфесом:

```
public interface MementoTarget
{
   public string Key { get; }

   public string void GetSaveData ();
   public void LoadData (string json);
}
```